# How to create a shadow border in CSS3?

Tags: css

I want the secret of creating this border:

[Image of the border that I want](http://im48.gulfup.com/IJWMYH.jpg)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. Don't let others do your work. What have you tried so far? Could you provide the link to the page where you found that border? Please read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```html
<div id="box">Content</div>
```

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  background: #ddd;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
  color: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 60px auto;
}


#box:before, #box:after {
  z-index: -1; 
  position: absolute; 
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%; 
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

#box:after {
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

See on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mv4vM/). The code is from this page: [How to create slick effects with CSS3 box-shadow](http://red-team-design.com/how-to-create-slick-effects-with-css3-box-shadow/).